Allow exceptionally to complete with more than one exception type in CompletableFuture
I have this method
private CompletableFuture<String> createCode(CodeRequest codeRequest) {
    return salesCompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> getVoucherCode(salesRequest), forkJoinPool.threadPool())
        .exceptionally(ServiceException::handleFutureException);
}

This is handleFutureException:
public static <T> T handleFutureException(Throwable ex) {
    if (ex instanceof CompletionException || ex instanceof ExecutionException) {
      if (ex.getCause() instanceof ServiceException) {
        throw new ServiceException((ServiceException) ex.getCause());
      } else {
        throw new ServiceException(ex.getCause().getMessage(), ex.getCause());
      }
    }
    else if (ex instanceof ServiceException exception) {
      throw new ServiceException(exception);
    }
    throw new ServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
  }

  public ServiceException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }
}

The only exception type this CompletableFuture will throw is ServiceException. Is it possible to change my code in some way that it could return ServiceWarningException if that indeed is the exception type and ServiceException for everything else?
I tried the below in handleFutureException but that does not work.
else if (ex instanceof ServiceWarningException exception) {
      throw new ServiceWarningException(exception);
}


What you want should indeed be possible and what you tried seems like you're going in the right direction. But you don't really give enough information to give a good answer. What is the full definition of ServiceException and ServiceWarningException? In other words, please provide a [mre]. And please explain what "doesn't work" means in the context of the example. Compiler error? Still only throws ServiceExcepton? Throws ServiceWarningException only some of the time it's supposed to? Something else?

Does ServiceWarningException extend ServiceException? If so, that new else if block should come before the else if (ex instanceof ServiceException exception) { block.

Why do you do throw new ServiceException(exception); in your original code instead of throw exception;?

What does public ServiceException(String message, Throwable cause) do in handleFutureException() method?

In your code
if (ex instanceof CompletionException || ex instanceof ExecutionException) {

} else if (ex instanceof ServiceException exception) {
  
}  else if (ex instanceof ServiceWarningException exception) {
  
}

checks of the type of the exception passed to exceptionally are meaningless because the exception will always be CompletionException.
Let's prove it.
The run method of the AsyncSupply class is
static final class AsyncSupply<T> extends ForkJoinTask<Void> implements Runnable, AsynchronousCompletionTask {
  public void run() {
      CompletableFuture<T> d; Supplier<? extends T> f;
      if ((d = dep) != null && (f = fn) != null) {
          dep = null; fn = null;
          if (d.result == null) {
              try {
                  d.completeValue(f.get());
              } catch (Throwable ex) {
                  d.completeThrowable(ex);
              }
          }
          d.postComplete();
      }
  }
}

This way, if an exception is thrown when calling the getVoucherCode(salesRequest) method, it will be caught and sent to the completeThrowable() method, which in turn will call encodeThrowable() to wrap your exception in a CompletionException.
final boolean completeThrowable(Throwable x) {
    return RESULT.compareAndSet(this, null, encodeThrowable(x));
}

static AltResult encodeThrowable(Throwable x) {
    return new AltResult((x instanceof CompletionException) ? x :
            wrapInCompletionException(x));
}

This way, your handleFutureException() handler will always receive only CompletionException.
Now let's consider what happens if you throw an exception in your exception handler.
The uniExceptionally() method is responsible for executing the code in your handleFutureException() handler.
final boolean uniExceptionally(Object r, Function<? super Throwable, ? extends T> f, UniExceptionally<T> c) {
    Throwable x;
    if (result == null) {
        try {
            if (c != null && !c.claim())
                return false;
            if (r instanceof AltResult && (x = ((AltResult)r).ex) != null)
                completeValue(f.apply(x));
            else
                internalComplete(r);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            completeThrowable(ex);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

If you throw your exception in handleFutureException() method, then the uniExceptionally() method catches it and sends it to the completeThrowable() method, which, as we discussed earlier, wraps your exception in a CompletionException again.
Therefore, you can never throw your own exception directly from the handleFutureException() method.
